# counting the unique words in a text file

Tags: python

Some of the unique words in the text file does not count and I've had no idea what's wrong in my code.

```
file = open('tweets2.txt','r')

unique_count = 0

lines = file.readlines()
line = lines[3]
per_word = line.split()

for i in per_word:
    if line.count(i) == 1:
        unique_count=unique_count + 1
        
print(unique_count)

file.close()
```

Here is the text file:
"I love REDACTED and Fiesta and all but can REDACTED host more academic-related events besides strand days???"

The output of this code is:
16

The expected output of the code came from the text file should be:
17

> "i will crack a raw egg on my head if REDACTED move the resumption of classes to Jan 7. im not even kidding."

The output of this code is:
20

The expected output of the code came from the text file should be:
23

Comment: Can you explain why you're skipping 3 lines

Comment: "i will crack a raw egg on my head if REDACTED move the resumption of classes to Jan 7. im not even kidding." is the 4th line of the txt file, however the first line starts at 0.

Comment: Did you mean `if per_word.count(i) == 1:`? If you do `if line.count(i) == 1:` then `"i"` for example will not be considered because it appears more than once in the whole line, but not as a word

Comment: If the data you're showing that purports to be "the text file" is as stated then you'll get an IndexError exception for *line = lines[3]* because there's only one line in the file

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the number of unique whitespace delimited tokens (case-sensitive) in the entire file then:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as infile:
  print(len(set(infile.read().split())))
```

Comment: Note this will not work if there is no space after any punctuation etc or of you have extra chars such as a dash with a space either side. Could use: 
```python
import re
some_string = "This is your sentence.It may contain a dash - or other*punctuation etc.Split the string using multiple delimiters!"
re.split('; |, |\*|\n|.',some_string)
```

Comment: oowww now i see thanks, you're such a blessing!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe count() works with chars not words, instead use python way with set() function to clear duplicated words?

```
per_word = set(line.split())
print (len(per_word))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are counting each word as a substring in the whole line because you do:

```
for i in per_word:
    if line.count(i) == 1:
```

So now some words are repeated as substrings, ***but not as words***. For example, the first word is `"i"`. `line.count("i")` gives 7 (it is also in `"if"`, `"im"`, etc.) so you don't count it as a unique word (even though it is). If you do:

```
for i in per_word:
    if per_word.count(i) == 1:
```

then you will count each word as a whole word and get the output you need.

---

Anyway this is very inefficient (`O(n^2)`) as you iterate over each word and then `count` iterates over the whole list again to count it. Either use a `set` as suggested in other answers or use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

unique_count = 0

line = "i will crack a raw egg on my head if REDACTED move the resumption of classes to Jan 7. im not even kidding."
per_word = line.split()

counter = Counter(per_word)
for count in counter.values():
    if count == 1:
        unique_count += 1

# Or simply
unique_count = sum(count == 1 for count in counter.values())

print(unique_count)
```